# Неблочная: НЕ слитно или раздельно?

Tags: частица-не

Ижевская ТЭЦ-1 состоит из неблочной части и парогазового энергоблока. 
Неблочная часть Ижевской ТЭЦ-1 – электростанция с поперечными связями 1934 года ввода в эксплуатацию.
Установленная электрическая мощность неблочной части составляет 60 мегаватт.

Answer (score 2):

Да, здесь слитно. **Неблочная** часть - некое новое качество, характеристика. Но не просто отрицание "блочной".

Ко всему прочему, при раздельном написании все фразы совершенно не воспринимается на глаз, особенно первая. "Состоит из не" - это нонсенс, не по-русски.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Слитное написание: Ижевская ТЭЦ-1 состоит **из неблочной части**.

**Из Интернета**: Компоновку электростанции из энергоблоков называют блочной. **Блочная** компоновка имеет ряд явных преимуществ перед **неблочной** — последняя применяется обычно лишь для неядерных ТЭС. Блочные ТЭС дешевле **неблочных** и т.д.

**Неблочный - это термин, поэтому  он пишется слитно**. Тем более он будет писаться слитно внутри **предложно- падежной формы** "из неблочной части".

Такие формы  практически всегда относятся к **утвердительным конструкциям**. Сравнить (две формы): город небольшой (утверждение), город не большой (отрицание), но: в небольшом городе (только утверждение).